# THEN ELSE condition statements in cypher query language in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to execute an CREATE statement in THEN and UPDATE in ELSE statement  in cypher query language in Neo4j.

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (product:user_product) WHERE id(product) = 45
OPTIONAL MATCH (user:person) where id(user) = 90 
FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN user IS NOT NULL THEN 
CREATE (user)<-[:HAS_USER]-(product)
ELSE 
set product.userStatus = 1
END)
return user, product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `collect` the user to a list while grouping by product and user, a list which will have a size of 0 or 1 as it won't contain `null`.

Then,

1. You can iterate on the list to do the `CREATE` part only when the user exists
2. You can iterate 0 or 1 time to set the property (or not, in the case of 0), if the size of the user list is 1 or 0

The resulting query is this:

```
MATCH (product:user_product) WHERE id(product) = 45
OPTIONAL MATCH (user:person) WHERE id(user) = 90
WITH product, user, collect(user) AS users
FOREACH (u IN users | CREATE (u)<-[:HAS_USER]-(product))
FOREACH (i in range(1, 1 - size(users)) | SET product.userStatus = 1)
RETURN user, product
```

Comment: If the 'user' node is null , then it throws an error that other node is null.

Comment: Indeed, I've added a `FOREACH` loop to guard the `CREATE`.

Comment: nice answer - i like the second `FOREACH` for updating the `product.userStatus`

Answer (score 2):

If either condition is true you could set a collection of one for the specific condition and then use `FOREACH` to loop through the condition if it is true. By combining them you optionally can perform one or the other.

```
MATCH (product:user_product) WHERE id(product) = 45
OPTIONAL MATCH (user:person) where id(user) = 90 
WITH CASE WHEN user IS NOT null THEN
  [1]
END as create_rel,
CASE WHEN user IS null THEN
  [1]
END as update_product, product, user
FOREACH (x in create_rel | 
  MERGE (user)<-[r:HAS_USER]-(product)
  ON CREATE set r.updated = 1
  ON MATCH set r.updated = r.updated + 1
)
FOREACH (x in update_product | 
  SET product.userStatus = 1
)
return user, product
```